# Count based on Or is not differentiating the count

Tags: t-sql

My results are showing both counts the same but there should be some that have different counts as CarCode is sometimes null.

```
SELECT  distinct car.carKey,            
    car.Weight,
    car.CarCode,
    COUNT(car.carKey)OVER(PARTITION BY car.carKey) AS TotalCarKeyCount,
    COUNT(Case When (car.[Weight] IS not null) and (car.CarCode is null) as CarCountWithoutCode 
           then 0 
       else car.carKey End) OVER(PARTITION BY car.carKey) AS CarCount
from car
```

results show `TotalCarKeyCount` and `CarCountWithoutCode` always with the same counts like the case statement isn't working or something.

Comment: The `case` statement isn't doing anything because you've wrapped in in a `count()` function.  For instance, `select count(select 0)` still returns `1`.  Both paths of the `case` statement return `1`...  It seems like you should use `sum(case when car.weight is not null and car.carcode is null then 0 else 1 end)`.  If this is the case, I'll post this as an answer so you can mark it correct :).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to use `SUM()` instead:

```
SELECT  distinct car.carKey,            
    car.Weight,
    car.CarCode,
    COUNT(car.carKey)OVER(PARTITION BY car.carKey) AS TotalCarKeyCount,
    SUM(Case When (car.[Weight] IS not null) and (car.CarCode is null) as CarCountWithoutCode 
           then 0 else 1 End) OVER(PARTITION BY car.carKey) AS CarCount
from car
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adae7/4) showing the difference between using `COUNT()` and `SUM()`:

```
create table test
(
  id int
);

insert into test values
(1), (null), (23), (4), (2);

select 
  count(case when id is null then 0 else id end) [count],
  sum(case when id is null then 0 else 1 end) [sum]
from test;
```

Count returns 5 and Sum returns 4.  Or you can change the `COUNT()` to use `null` and the `null` values will be excluded in the final `count()`

```
select 
  count(case when id is null then null else id end) [count],
  sum(case when id is null then 0 else 1 end) [sum]
from test;
```

Your query would be:

```
SELECT  distinct car.carKey,            
    car.Weight,
    car.CarCode,
    COUNT(car.carKey)OVER(PARTITION BY car.carKey) AS TotalCarKeyCount,
    COUNT(Case When (car.[Weight] IS not null) and (car.CarCode is null) as CarCountWithoutCode 
           then null else 1 End) OVER(PARTITION BY car.carKey) AS CarCount
from car
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `then 0` to `then null`. Zero values are counted, nulls are not.